# How to specify this in an object literal with flow in js

Tags: javascript, flowtype, object-literal

I am using `// @flow strict` but somehow it does not work properly in an object literal when using `this`. `this` seemed to be interpreted as any.

This is the example code

```
type TestType = {
  arr: Array<number>,
  fun: () => void,
}

const testObject: TestType = {
  arr:[],
  fun(){
    this.arr.toUpperCase();
  }
}

testObject.fun();
```

**How can I tell flow that it knows that `this.arr.toUpperCase()` is not existing, because `this.arr` is an Array?**

Answer (score 1):

There seems to [no way](http://In%20Flow%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20type%20annotate%20this%20and%20Flow%20will%20check%20whatever%20context%20you%20call%20the%20function%20with.) to explicitly define `this` type in function:

> In Flow you don’t type annotate this and Flow will check whatever context you call the function with.

As a workaround you [can do something like:](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbmgXigbwFBSgQwCcCAuKAQSLxAB4A7AVwFsAjCAgPgBocoAze2qQAUASiip2UAG4B7AJYATbgF8sWAMYzaiKMATAA8swBWEdcFJxEySOMw9CJANoBdbrn61R2XLk3bgTEdlS30bNF0ACzl4AG4eXEcAOmAZAFUwSAIAYTx4CFF43FVVLD1EI1NzJM9CrCA):

```
const testObject: TestType = {
  arr:[],
  fun(){
    const {arr}: TestType = this;
    arr.toUpperCase();
  }
}

testObject.fun();
```